# What is the difference between the design of algorithms and the analysis of algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, terminology

I am new to algorithms. What is the difference between the *design* of algorithms and the *analysis* of algorithms?

Comment: Well a good dictionary will give you the answer, design and analysis are very different things (whatever the fields they are applied to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *design* of an algorithm is the process of inventing the algorithm. You work out what steps to take, the order in which to take them, etc. (Think of it like writing the code for the algorithm). The *analysis* of an algorithm is where you work out mathematically how efficient it is, prove that it's correct in all cases, etc.

Think of the design as writing the code and the analysis as justifying why that code works and why it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm Design** is a specific instructions for completing a task.
They've also been called "recipes".Perhaps a more accurate description would be that algorithms design are patterns for completing a task in an efficient way.

**Analysis of Algorithms** is the determination of the amount of resources (such as time and storage) necessary to execute them.usually described as (**time complexity**) and storage locations (**space complexity**) of an algorithm and stated as a **function** relating the input length to the number of steps.